# Using Django's m2m_changed to modify what is being saved pre_add

Tags: python, django, django-signals, django-orm, m2m

I am not very familiar with Django's signals and could use some help.

How do I modified the pk_set before the instance is saved?  Do I have to return something to the signal caller (like the `kwargs`)?  Or do I save the `instance` myself?

As a simplified example: I wanted to ensure the Category with `pk=1` is included with all my Videos when they are saved. How would I do that with `m2m_changed`?

```
class Video(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField('Category')

def video_category_changed(sender, **kwargs):
    action = kwargs.pop('action', None)
    pk_set = kwargs.pop('pk_set', None)
    instance = kwargs.pop('instance', None)

    if action == "pre_add":
        if 1 not in pk_set:
            pk_set.update( [ 1 ] )  # adding this to the set
            # do something else?
            # profit?

m2m_changed.connect( video_category_changed, sender=Video.category.through )
```

Comment: It's not required to return values in signals. You also don't need to save the instance. Just add the code to be executed on response to the selected events.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Just updating the `pk_set` is sufficient. You don't need to do any extra work. Once the video instance is saved, it will have a category with pk=1.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Category(models.Model):
    pass

class Video(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField('Category')

@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Video.category.through)
def video_category_changed(sender, **kwargs):
    action = kwargs.pop('action', None)
    pk_set = kwargs.pop('pk_set', None)    
    if action == "pre_add":
        if 1 not in pk_set:
            pk_set.update([1])
```

In the above method, the categories will be saved only after the video instance is saved. If you want to EXPLICITLY save them in the `m2m_changed` instance, you can also do that as follows.

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Video.category.through)
def video_category_changed(sender, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs.pop('instance', None)
    pk_set = kwargs.pop('pk_set', None)
    action = kwargs.pop('action', None)
    if action == "pre_add":
        if 1 not in pk_set:
            c = Category.objects.get(pk=1)
            instance.category.add(c)
            instance.save()
```

Comment: It's funny how little things stump you sometimes -- I didn't have a `pk=1` category object when I was testing this ... so, when it didn't work I assumed I was missing something with the signal since it's the first time I'd worked with those ... when in fact, I was just being silly and had it right to begin with.  Thanks for the very clear answer with example.  Nailed it.