# Get selected values of ManytoMany field in django model save method

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-admin

I am trying to add data to a table **BillRecord** from Django admin.I need to access selected values of **ManytoMany** field in model **save** method and need to do some logic depending upon the selected objects of ManytoMany field.

```
class ProductType(BaseApplicationModel):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Product(BaseApplicationModel)
   type = models.ForeignKey(ProductType,related_name="products")

class BillRecord(BaseApplicationModel):
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name="billrecords")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(BillRecord, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
       for product in self.products.all():
          print product
```

In the code when I tried to print the values of product it gives me `billing.Product.None` that is `self.products.all()` returns empty queryset

I need to get the ID's of the selected objects in the ManyToMany field select box. [image: picture]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `BillRecord` instance is not *always* saved when a `Product` is associated with it. With a many to many relation, you can save either object first. The correct way to deal with it is to use the [m2m-changed signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#m2m-changed):

> Sent when a ManyToManyField is changed on a model instance. Strictly speaking, this is not a model signal since it is sent by the ManyToManyField, but since it complements the pre_save/post_save and pre_delete/post_delete when it comes to tracking changes to models, it is included here.

So you should try something like the following:

```
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed

...your models here...

def products_changed(sender, **kwargs):
    # Do something here
    pass

m2m_changed.connect(products_changed, sender=BillRecord.products.through)
```

Comment: After adding what you mentioned I'm getting `AttributeError: type object 'BillRecord_products' has no attribute 'product_set'`

Comment: @albinantony143 Sorry, I hadn't tested it as it was given as an example. In this case you can access `instance` keyword argument (using `kwargs.pop("instance")`) and use it as your `BillRecord` instance.

Comment: `kwargs.pop("instance")` gives me an instance of `BillRecord`. And when I tried to print `print kwargs.pop("instance").products` its still giving me `billing.Product.None`. Is there any way by I can get the ID's of ManyToMany field objects.

Comment: You should read the documentation I linked to, but I think you can access them using `pk_set` argument.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26493254/using-djangos-m2m-changed-to-modify-what-is-being-saved-pre-add

Answer (score 0):

There are three kind of action in m2m: add, remove, clean

the signal @receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Model.manytomanyfield.through) iterate actions:

first:

pre-remove and post-remove: if some objects are removed from your manytomanyfield
then to pre-add, here you can access to your selected (new) values and to the instance (with the removed objects of manytomanyfield).
You could write something like that to get them:

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=ProductVariation.combination.through)
```

def check_attribute(sender, **kwargs):
instance = kwargs['instance']

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
if kwargs['action'] == 'pre_add':
    if kwargs.get('pk_set'):
        product_attributes = instance.combination.all() | \
                             ProductAttribute.objects.filter(id__in=kwargs.get('pk_set'))
        groups_count = product_attributes.values('attribute').annotate(Count('id'))
        for group in groups_count:
            if group.get('id__count', 0) > 1:
                attribute_name = Attribute.objects.get(id=group['attribute'])
                rai
```